# How to request management to provide us a cab?

Tags: professionalism, management, india

We (around 10 people) live a longer distance from office location, and coming by public transport is very hard as we need to travel through 3 buses at least. It is also hard for us to travel by private vehicles even. So we decided to ask management to provide us a daily cab to reach the facility. How can we approach in a professional way to put in our request?

Note: We are willing to pay for it.

Comment: I think I am still missing something. If you say you are willing to pay for it, then what exactly are you asking your company to do?

Comment: Look into Van pooling.

Comment: Y downvote can the one who voted me down can explain please I want to improve myself and want to know wrong in this question.

Comment: @CGCampbell what is Van pooling?

Comment: We want company to provide us cab facility because it will be professional in some way @DavidK

Comment: Probably not an option for you. I failed to notice your location tag.

Comment: @CGCampbell I actually added the India tag because Happy commented on my answer and said that it is not uncommon for IT companies in India to provide transportation for their employees.

Comment: Why can't you organise your own cab?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, You all do a meeting and discuss it. It should be clear who is going to explain and what. The group should be united.

That said, You need to present it to management as a business plan, you need to list and explain the points in such a way that management realizes its benefits. One obvious advantage of having a cab is that you reach office on time and are not tired at the beginning of your shift. Energetic employes will be able to solve more problems during the day so that will definitely increase your productivity and company's gains. It will be great if you can provide information about how much it will cost monthly and yearly. Remember, In corporate management is only interested in maximizing the gains so if it is not important for them in most cases they won't do it.

Be ready to accept **NO**, if they deny your request that means company doesn't see any advantage of providing you cab facility. Don't have that in your heart for future.

As an alternate solution your group can still arrange a cab together on fix monthly rentals. In that case you all will have to bear the cost.

Comment: Loved your answer but only upvote from me for know I need to see many answers thanks :)

Comment: The other solution is carpooling or van-pooling. Or simply relocating closer to work.

Comment: and yes we are ready to pay for cab the only thing we need to have is to reach office without any troubles.

Comment: @dh47 I am glad, you loved my answer... Yes having a cab to reach office is really good. It solves half of your problems :)

Comment: _As an alternate solution your group can still arrange a cab together on fix monthly rentals. In that case you all will have to bear the cost._ Yes we are thinking in that way too but firstly we want to go in an official way :)

Answer (score 3):

**Disclaimer: This answer is given with a US mindset. The OP is from India, where companies commonly arrange transport for their employees.**

I know this isn't the answer you are looking for, but

**You don't.**

I have never once heard of a company paying for the cost of their employees' daily commute. Part of choosing a company and choosing where to live is determining how long your commute is. I know people who drive 2-3 hours each way to get to and from work and are fine with that. I left a job, in part, because my hour long drive was too much for me.

It was your choice to live so far from the office, not the company's. If your commute is wearing on you, then it is up to *you* to find and pay for a solution, not your company. Between the 10 of you, you should be able to come up with an alternative. Like aProgrammer, I recommend looking into splitting cabs or carpooling if you don't want to take public transit.

Comment: It is quite common in India for IT companies to arrange transport for its employees. Of course, there are some restrictions, but OP is in India, and your answer is not relevant to his/her context.

Comment: @Happy, would you mind adding that info to the question then? There is no way anyone unfamiliar with Indian norms could have known that.

Comment: Here in Belgium, public transport commute is frequently paid partly or fully by the employer. I wouldn't diss the idea since carpooling is also sponsored by the employer in Belgium/The Netherlands.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel, Having the employer pay for public transit or ride sharing I have always considered more of an environmental incentive than an employment benefit.

Comment: @David Yes, there was indeed no way for you to know that. My comment wasn't meant to be accusative, I am sorry if you got that impression. My intention was only to point out to the readers that your answer is valid in a different setting, and may not be relevant to the OP's context.

Comment: `I have never once heard of a company paying for the cost of their employees' daily commute. `  At least two large, well-known Silicon Valley tech companies supply bus transportation for their employees.

Comment: @Blrfl I think we can all agree that the Googles and Facebooks of the world are not the norm when it comes to employment perks.

Comment: I hate to split hairs, but "not the norm" and "never once heard of" aren't the same thing.

Comment: In Silicon Valley, it is actually common for the non-Facebooks and the non-Googles Tech companies to subsidize daily commuting, whether be it public transportation or Uber/Lyfts/Vanpools. It's a pre-tax fringe benefit which is capped at $255 per month according to the IRS. The company can subsidize more, but the surplus is taxed. And in some cases, if a company wants a new building/expansion permit without expanding its parking lot, it makes the promise directly to the city zoning department to mitigate the impact on traffic and daily neighborhood parking from additional employees.

Comment: But daily commuting is also subsidized by fast food places and retail establishments in San Francisco and in Silicon Valley for minimum wage workers as well (through services like https://www.chariot.com/ ). One of the biggest problems is that minimum wage workers can't afford to live close to the cities that have all the jobs. So they end up accepting the first job they find, but they don't last long as employees because their daily public transportation commute is atrocious and eventually they're able to find a job closer to where they live.